# DataBinding Component is not converted into Object

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind the `visibility` of a `Cardview` with a condition based `boolean` from the view model using `databinding`.

But I'm getting databinding error

I've tried to use databinding and handling the `visibility` inside the `xml` itself.
I've also tried to handle the `visibility` programmatically from within the fragment as well.
But both examples fail

```xml
<variable name="vm"
                  type="packageName.ui.viewmodels.DashHomeViewModel"/>

android:visibility="@{vm.showQRCard == true ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

```
val binder = DataBindingUtil
.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dash_home, container, false)
binder.vm = viewModel
```

I'm getting this error message.

> error: constructor FragmentDashHomeBinding in class FragmentDashHomeBinding cannot be applied to given types;
>           super(bindingComponent, root, 2
>           ^
>     required: Object,View,int,AppBarLayout,LinearLayout,LinearLayout,ImageView,SwipeRefreshLayout,Toolbar,CircleImageView,TextView,TextView,TextView,FrameLayout,FrameLayout,FrameLayout,FrameLayout
>     found: DataBindingComponent,View,int,AppBarLayout,LinearLayout,LinearLayout,ImageView,ImageView,SwipeRefreshLayout,Toolbar,CircleImageView,TextView,TextView,TextView,TextView,FrameLayout,FrameLayout,FrameLayout,FrameLayout
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

What I understand from the error is that `Object` is expected but `DataBindingComponent` is passed, but `DataBindingComponent` is automatically converted to an `object` which is not happening in this case.
I don't know the reason behind this.

It's happening in this specific case only as similar code in other fragments for visibility is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know why but when I tried to run my code today it worked perfectly.
I had tried clean code and invalidate cache and restart yesterday but it did not work.